# functions in class: one is seen, but the other one is ignored

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm currently working on a little game using SFML and C++, but I have a problem. I have a class Character in character.h with 2 functions inside, but when I try to access these functions in an other file (Game.cpp), one works perfectly while the other acts as if it doesn't even exist. Since this is my first post, and I don't know how to properly showcase my code, so please tell me if I'm not clear enough.
Thanks to all of you and have a good day.

error message: 
[image]

```
/****CHARACTER.H****/
#ifndef CHARACTER_H
#define CHARACTER_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Character{

public:
    Character();
    ~Character();
    void initPlayer(string& fileName, sf::IntRect rect);
    void moveCharacter();
    sf::Sprite m_sprite;

private:
    sf::VertexArray m_vertices;
    sf::Texture m_texture;

};

#endif





/****CHARACTER.CPP*****/
#include "/home/hichem/C++/sfml/Game Engine/character.h"
#include "string"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Character::Character(){


}

Character::~Character(){

}

void Character::initPlayer(string& fileName, sf::IntRect rect){
    if (!m_texture.loadFromFile(fileName, rect)){
        cout << "failed to load image" << endl;
    }
    m_sprite.setTexture(m_texture);
    m_sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(400, 200));
 }

void Character::moveCharacter(){

}



/****GAME.H****/
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "character.h"
#include "tileMap.h"
#include "string"

class Game: public sf::Transformable{
    public:
        Game();
        ~Game();
        void run(sf::RenderWindow &window);


    private:
        void event(sf::RenderWindow &window);
        void update();
        void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window);
        TileMap carte;
        Character player;
        const int level_1[128] =
        {
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        };

};

#endif // GAME_H



/****GAME.CPP****/
#include "Game.h"

using namespace std;
Game::Game(){
    string a = "images/tiles.png";
    carte.load(a, sf::Vector2u(50, 50), level_1, 16, 8);
    string b = "images/player.png";

    /*FUNCTION THAT WORKS FROM CHARACTER.H*/
    player.initPlayer(b, sf::IntRect(0,0,50,50));
}

Game::~Game(){
    //dtor
}

void Game::event(sf::RenderWindow &window){
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)){
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        /*FUNCTION THAT DOES NOT WORKS FROM CHARACTER.H*/
        player.moveCharacter();
    }
}

void Game::update(){

}

void Game::draw(sf::RenderWindow &window){
    window.clear();
    window.draw(carte);
    window.draw(player.m_sprite);
    window.display();
}

void Game::run(sf::RenderWindow &window){
    while(window.isOpen()){
        event(window);
        update();
        draw(window);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue? Is it not compiling? Or does it not do anything?

Comment: Copy any compilation errors or erroneous output you are getting as **text** and paste to the body of the question.

Comment: Drop a #error in the top of your character.h header (inside the include-guard) and make damn sure character.cpp, when compiled, is pulling in the header you think. It doesn't look like it, and judging by the `#include` hyjinx/differences, it seems you may suspect that as well. Your error isn't the marked line. the original error is in character.cpp, which says your member doesn't exist. Clearly it does exist in the header you provided here.

Comment: You are includin a wrong .h file. Check the paths. Don't include with an absolute path.

Comment: You should avoid `using namespace std;`, especially in header files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys!, I was really tired last night and didn't noticed that I was linking the wrong path in character.cpp